# Is there a way to get a transcript of a Google Meet call?

Tags: google-meet

Does Google Meet offer transcripts that can be downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately they do not.  There are a number of services that add this capability to Google Meet.  Here's an example of how to get a transcript from google meet using a transcription service [Scribbl.co](https://www.scribbl.co):

### 1. Copy joining info from google meet:

[image]

### 2. Paste joining info into Scribbl

[image]

### 3. Click Join Scribbl to Call

[image]

### 4. Your transcript will stream in live!

[image]